# Assigning a value to a variable passed to a function causes a segmentation fault.

Tags: function, fortran

Consider this simple program:

```
  program foo
  integer bar,idum

  print * , bar(1)
  end program


  function bar(idum)
      integer idum,bar
      print * , idum
      idum =  2
      bar =  2
      return
  end
```

When I run it, I get a segmentation fault upon the line `idum = 2`

```
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
           1

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040081b in bar (idum=1) at play.f:11
11            idum =  2
```

Am I not allowed to assign values to variables passed to a function? how can I use them as flags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass a literal value `1` to the function. Then you try to change it in

```
idum =  2
```

That is not allowed. The code tries to change the literal constant and crashes, because that is not possible.

If you want to change a value inside a function, then a) it must be a **variable**, not a constant value, b) it must be passed by value (Fortran 2003).

In modern Fortran **always** use explicit interfaces. I mean **ALWAYS**. Either use modules (preferred!!!), or, in simple cases, use internal functions like:

```
  program foo
    integer bar,idum

    print * , bar(1)

  contains

    function bar(idum)
      integer idum,bar
      print * , idum
      idum =  2
      bar =  2
      return
    end function
  end program
```

The compiler may be able to tell you you are doing it wrong. Especially so, if you specify `intent` for the argument:

```
function bar(idum)
   integer bar
   integer, intent(in) :: idum
```

The compiler *will* complain now. It will also complain with other intent's.  And you can then fix the code to make the compiler happy.

And **ALWAYS!!!!!** use `IMPLICIT NONE`. This is not optional. It is necessary.